# unable to compute gradients for non-differentiable external library function when using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow2.0, gradient, backpropagation

i have a function that is not differentiable in the tensorflow graph, my constraints are here

I can't generate large datasets for the surrogate model.
I can't use gradient-free methods.
I can't modify the external library which is not differentiable.
I need to train using gradients.

do anybody have idea how to proceed with this problem, i am trying to use finite difference approach but gradients got constant. An example will be highly appreciated.